# Children get "auto centered" around parent in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, parent-child

In a 2D Unity game, I have a GameObject the creates some children from prefabs. I do it this way:

```c#
var NewShip = Instantiate(ShipPrefab, Position, Quaternion.identity);
NewShip.transform.SetParent(transform, false);
```

However, the full pack of children get positioned "around" the parent. The parent is always in the center of the children.

This is the pack of children with the parent selected:
[image: parent selected]

And this is the first child select:

[image: child selecte]

No matter this child is in (0,0,0), it is not visually in the same position as its parent.

Being honest, this was my initial intent. Was prepared to write some code to get this "free" result. No matter what, I would like to know why this happens.

Comment: Probably because you've got your pivot mode in "center" rather than "pivot." https://i.stack.imgur.com/4WHAt.png

Comment: You're right, thank you.